# Multiple Radio Buttons with its related Checkboxes

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, radio-button

I'm working on a project (using the CodeIgniter framework) which contains a grid with a lot of checkboxes. On selecting a checkbox, a pop up (twitter bootstrap - modal) appears which contains statements and its respective sub-statements. Statements are to be selected using radio buttons and sub-statements are to be selected using checkboxes.

Eg: If I select the 1st statement, then I'm supposed to select its respective sub-statements and not that of the 2nd. In order to avoid selecting the other sub-statements, I have to disable them. How can I do that?

radio1: statement 1     (enable - selected)
      chckbox1: sub-stmt1 (selected)
      chckbox2: sub-stmt2 (may be selected or may not be)

radio2: statement 2     (enable - not selected)
      chckbox1: sub-stmt1 (disable)
      chckbox2: sub-stmt2 (disable)
      chckbox3: sub-stmt3 (disable)

radio3: statement 3     (enable - not selected)
      chckbox1: sub-stmt1 (disable)

I'm using nested for loops, one for generating radio buttons (statements) and another for checkboxes (sub-statements).

Comment: Did you want to do this with jQuery?

Comment: He will need javascript anyway to open/close popup, to switch sub-statements, to..

Comment: Please post your answer as an *answer*, not a *comment* to the question. Also, to make this question relevant to others in future, please post the relevant html.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a different way

//hide checkboxes of other radio buttons if they are not selected selected

$(function() {

```
   $('#comment').on('change', '.toggle-family', function() { 

       if ($(this).attr('checked')) { 

            $("[name='cbox[]']").addClass('hide'); 
            $('.pi_'+$(this).val()).removeClass('hide'); 
       } 
   });
```

});

Thank you guys.